How to map table references in a JSON file to corresponding values in an Excel file using Python?
I have an Excel file containing a list of requirements in 1 column and a JSON file that stores table values. The requirements in the Excel file include references to tables in the JSON file, formatted as "table x" where x is a number. Not every requirement has a corresponding table.
For example, a requirement might state: "The mass of the CubeSat shall not extend the values of table 3." The format of the table references in the requirements is always "table x" with x being any number.
This is the JSON-file
{
    "table 3": {
        "footprint_cs_2u": "100x100 mm",
        "height_cs_2u": "227 mm",
        "feet_cs_2u": "8.5x8.5 mm",
        "rails_edges_rounded_2u": "Rx1mm",
        "footprint_cs_3u": "100x100 mm",
        "height_cs_3u": "340.5 mm",
        "feet_cs_3u": "8.5x8.5 mm",
        "rails_edges_rounded_3u": "Rx1mm"
        }
}
        

What I managed to do was to read and save the 1 Excel column via the .iloc[:,0] -command to create a dataframe and read the JSON-file.
I saw that you might be able to use RegEx and the re.search()-command to find matches but I could not figure out an implementation and what to do afterwards.
In this manner:
import re

#Check if the string starts with "The" and ends with "Spain":

txt = "The rain in Spain"
x = re.search("^The.*Spain$", txt)

This is my full-code if it helps.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
import re
import openpyxl


def translate_requirements(input_excel, tables_json, output_latex):
    # read Excel-file
    df = pd.read_excel(input_excel)

    # read JSON file
    with open(tables_json, 'r') as file:
        tables = json.load(file)


    # create dataframe for 1-column Excel content.
    requirements = df.iloc[:, 0]

    # Initialize translated requirements (empty array)
    translated_requirements = []

    # Output as LaTeX file | Here: example-doc
    with open(output_latex, 'w') as latex:
        latex.write(r"""
            \documentclass{article}
            .
            .
            .
            """
        )

translate_requirements('input.xlsx', 'tables.json', 'output_latex.tex')

print('Data read')

So far, I can read both the Excel and JSON files. However, I need help with adding the table contents from the JSON-file into the corresponding Excel column of the requirement that uses that table.
How can I achieve this mapping, and subsequently include this information in the LaTeX document?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

I don't understand what for you need regex with ^ $. If you need to find table 3 in Excel text  then use like table \d+. And later use this value to get data from JSON.

I'm still new to StackOverflow so I don't know how much information is necessary, I just wanted to showcase an example and not create confusion, my apologies.

You can search table \d+ in text
import re

text = 'The mass of the CubeSat shall not extend the values of table 3.'
results = re.findall('table \d+', text)

print(results)

Result:
['table 3']

And later you can check if list is not empty and use first results[0] (or all results) to search table in json.
if results:
    table = tables[results[0]]
    # ... work with table ...

And if you have more elements then use for-loop to find all values and put on list
requirements  = df.iloc[:, 0].to_list()

data = []

for text in requirements:
    results = re.findall('table \d+', text)
    if results:
        table = tables[results[0]]
        data.append( (text, table) )

and later use this list to generate latex
but in this place you have to decide how to format it (and I skip it)
with open(output_latex, 'w') as latex:
    latex.write(r"\documentclass{article}\n")

    for text, table in data:
        latex.write(f"{text} ....{table}\n")

